# Keep seeing "Unexpected response code: 502"

Tags: support

I have been seeing this since a while, but whenever I load a page on stackoverflow.com or meta.stackoverflow.com I see `Unexpected response code: 502` in the console on Chrome.

It is innocuous for me, but I am guessing that these 502's are the result of extraneous calls which must add some server strain.

Update: seems that the WebSockets are to blame. From the HAR:

```
{ "name": "Host" , "value": "sockets-se.or.stackexchange.com" },
```

And when I visit *sockets-se.or.stackexchange.com* I get

*502 Bad Gateway, The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.*

Comment: Quit straining our servers!

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature!

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII may i ask how its that feature ?

Comment: You can't directly browse to web sockets host, it's giving 502 even when it's all OK. Anyway, go to the Network tab of Chrome Developer Tools and click the "sockets-se.or.stackexchange.com" entry. There should be Frames tab, what you see there?

Comment: The Status is success but the type is Pending, since the count of websocket calls is always equal to the count of 502 alerts, I assume it is not really a success ;) Also I cannot look at request header or response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response code 502 when connecting to our socket server is also dished out by some proxy servers that are not able to deal with web sockets.  I have seen this happen when using a 3G mobile connection.

Comment: This only happens for me in one location, so that must be it.